# Intercepting cxf web service header with Apache Camel (Java DSL)

Tags: apache-camel, cxf, wss4j

I created a web service client to handle cxf soap web services with apache camel.

```
String serviceUri = "cxf:http://localhost:10000/myservice?serviceClass=" + 
    MyRequest.class.getCanonicalName();

from(uri).to("mock:xyz");
```

The web service receives the soap call but throws an exception since the request requires a handling for wss.

*`org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: MustUnderstand headers: [{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd}Security] are not understood.`*

The reason is, that the service requires ws security, which can be seen by lloking at the request.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Header><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
```

I found out that I need to implement an interceptor to handle header properties.

**My questions:**

- How can I add an interceptor to handle the header attributes with Camel Java-DSL?
- Will this be sufficient to get rid of the SOAP Fault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it through 
cxfEndpointConfigurer option @see:  [Camel-CXF configuration](http://camel.apache.org/cxf.html)

(I use Spring (it is much easier)), but I guess for DSL URI will look like:

```
String serviceUri = "cxf:http://localhost:10000/myservice?serviceClass=" + 
MyRequest.class.getCanonicalName() +
"&cxfEndpointConfigurer="+ MyConfigurer.class.getCanonicalName();
```

by implementing org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfEndpointConfigurer you have ability to add an Interceptor inside configureServer method

```
server.getEndpoint().getInInterceptors().add(new MyJAASLoginInterceptor());
```

if you run your Camel in container with JAAS (like JBOSS) you can use extension from

```
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.security.JAASLoginInterceptor
```

with needed callback handler. 
Simple example which validates user/password from WSS header against JBOSS users:

```
public class MyJAASLoginInterceptor extends javax.security.auth.callback.JAASLoginInterceptor {

  @Override
  protected CallbackHandler getCallbackHandler(String name, String password) {

    return new org.apache.cxf.interceptor.security.NamePasswordCallbackHandler(name, password, "setCredential");

  }

}
```

Comment: unfortunately "&cxfEndpointConfigurer="+ MyConfigurer.class.getCanonicalName(); is not working, I get the error message "Could not find a suitable setter for property: cxfEndpointConfigurer as there isn't a setter method with same type: java.lang.String nor type conversion possible: "

Comment: pls. read this: http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/cxfEndpointConfigurer-in-an-URI-td5773083.html